# How can keep apscheduler executer in different app and adding job in different app

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am adding job in `django` application which can add job in `MySQL` `jobstore` using `SqlAlchemy`.

I want `apscheduler` to run in the job in different application(using `background` `apscheduler`)

Few problems I am facing.

1. jobs are running in same application where i am adding job which is issue  job requires heavy compute and it has nothing to do with`application`
2. if I don't `start scheduler` It doesn't save job in jobstore and keeps it in `pending jobs`
3. even If I start new scheduler in new application . **sometime it deleltes job forcefully from MYSQL** if any kind of issue found in job.
4. Even I wrote custom `sheduler` changes done in code below,

```
    with self._jobstores_lock:
        if self.state == STATE_STOPPED:
            self._pending_jobs.append((job, jobstore, replace_existing))
            self._logger.info('Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when '
                              'the scheduler starts')
        else:
            self._real_add_job(job, jobstore, replace_existing)
```

Comment: What do you mean "run in different application"? Do you mean using another process? Or a whole new Python interpreter? For the former one, you can use `ProcessExecutor` instead of the default `ThreadExecutor`, for the later one, I cannot figure out why you need it.

Comment: Fully independent application in different location which takes job from jobstore and run jobs only

Comment: Have you read the [FAQ](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-share-a-single-job-store-among-one-or-more-worker-processes)?

Comment: Yeah ,everything was working fine .. the requirement changed to do separate both .. if there is a way it will will be helpful